# Tkinter Print function[filedialog]

Tags: python, printing, tkinter

Is there a command in Tkinter that allows the program to pop up a window that lets the user pick a printer from the list of drivers that they have installed?

Sorry that I can't provide any details, but I haven't found anything about this topic on the web.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You'll  have to create your own popup window for that specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wasn't sure